# C# Base Object not Serializable in New Unity Project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a demo to show a classmate how to create a object that stores persistent data. It essentially stores an object into a serializable list. The script works for a game that I originally created it for, however when I transfer the contents of the script into another project, I receive an error.
It reads,

`"Field data is a member of PersistentData which is serializable, but is of type object which is not serializable."`

Both projects use Unity version 2020.1.3f1.
Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHjvh.png) of both of the projects side by side.

I've checked the compiler being used in both projects and have found they use the same version, `v4.0.30319`

What perplexes me is the fact that this script works even though `System.object` should not be serializable. It works flawlessly to store and read data from disk, yet it breaks completely when transferred to a new project. I have also tried some more things. I have tried exporting and importing the script, and even just copy and pasting the raw code into a similarly named file in a new project. None of these have worked. If anyone wants my project files to further inspect, that would be greatly appreciated.

And here is the raw code for the `PersistentData` object:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class PersistentData
{
    public object data;
    public System.Type type { get { return data.GetType(); } }
    public PersistentData(object data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

`PersistentData` is created by the object `DataList`. `Datalist` has a dictionary for a string key and `PersistentData` pair. The `DataManager` is what the client interacts with. The manager can load, save, and change the data that is stored within a the `DataList`. Here is the raw code for both objects:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

public class DataStore : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static DataStore instance;
    static string DATAPATH = "";

    DataList data = new DataList();

    bool exists { get { return File.Exists(DATAPATH); } }

    private void Awake()
    {
        DATAPATH = Application.persistentDataPath + "/USRDAT.bin";
        Debug.Log(DATAPATH);
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Cannot create multiple instances of DataStore!");
            Destroy(this);
        }
        //check if data store already exists, and, if so, load it
        LoadData();
    }

    //Util functions

    public bool SaveData()
    {
        if(data != null)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var dat = File.Open(DATAPATH, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                    formatter.Serialize(dat, data);
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Debug.Log("Could not save data!");
                Debug.LogError(e);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        if (exists)
        {
            try
            {
                Debug.Log("Loading datastore");
                using (var stream = File.Open(DATAPATH, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                    data = (DataList)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                Debug.Log("Failed to save datalist");
                Debug.LogError(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public void SetData(object data, string name)
    {
        this.data.SetPersistentData(data, name);
    }
    public void DelData(string field)
    {
        this.data.RemovePersistentData(field);
    }
    public PersistentData GetData(string field)
    {
        return data.GetPersistentData(field);
    }
}


//Data contains a sorted list of PersistentData and provides api for getting and setting data

[System.Serializable]
public class DataList
{
    public Dictionary<string, PersistentData> fields = new Dictionary<string, PersistentData>();
    public DataList(Dictionary<string, PersistentData> list)
    {
        fields = list;
    }
    public DataList(){}

    public void SetPersistentData(object data, string fieldName)
    {
        validName(fieldName);
        fields[fieldName] = new PersistentData(data);
    }

    public void RemovePersistentData(string field)
    {
        fields.Remove(field);
    }

    public PersistentData GetPersistentData(string field)
    {
        try
        {
            var dat = fields[field];
            return dat;
        }
        catch(KeyNotFoundException e)
        {
            Debug.Log("The key '"+field+"' was not present.");
        }
        return null;
    }

    bool validName(string name)
    {
        if (fields.ContainsKey(name))
        {
            return true;
        }
        Debug.Log("Non-unique field name: "+name+"\nUpdating field instead of making new.");
        return false;
    }

    PersistentData GetData(string field)
    {
        return fields[field];
    }
}
```

I think that somehow one project is using a different version of C#, but I don't know how I would check this.

Comment: Are they both IL2CPP or Mono?

Comment: Both projects are Mono

Answer (score 0):

You had:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PersistentData
{
    public object data;
```

Lower-case `object` is a `System.object`.  This type is not Serializable.

Did you mean to have upper-case `Object`, from `UnityEngine.Object` ?

Comment: I don't think this is the case, as it works perfectly fine in a game I created it for initially. You can see this in the image with both the new project and the game project. There is no difference between them, and there is no difference between the unity version, which leads me to believe there is a difference in C# compiler.

Comment: Hmm. Fair.  You can check the compiler in ```Edit > Project Settings > Player > Other```

Comment: I've updated my initial post. Both projects are using the same version of C#.